# How to make the following table split in 2 pages?

Tags: tables, tabularx, overleaf

Please help me make the following table split in two pages. I've tried using longtable and tabularx but it didn't work, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.215em}rrr|rrrr}
    F1    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F2} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.4736 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 2E-189 & 0.00E+00 & 2.84143 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.17197 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 2E-184 & 0.00E+00 & 2.93863 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.84918 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.54477 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.78398 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 1E-197 & 0.00E+00 & 2.80703 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.18185 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.57635 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.03508 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA5}} & \textbf{5E-201} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.00535 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.33305 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.84252 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.05392 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 5E-197 & 0.00E+00 & 3.04812 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.03381 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 2E-196 & 0.00E+00 & 3.17601 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.00061 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 3.01033 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.07614 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.4786 \\
    \midrule
    F3    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F4} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.09959 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 7E-182 & 0.00E+00 & 2.37899 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.55129 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 4E-183 & 0.00E+00 & 3.05523 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.33676 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 1E-198 & 0.00E+00 & 2.65456 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.2895 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 2E-195 & 0.00E+00 & 2.95612 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.29967 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 2E-195 & 0.00E+00 & 2.65462 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.39968 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 1E-195 & 0.00E+00 & 2.90607 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.461 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 4E-205 & 0.00E+00 & 3.27635 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.35422 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA7}} & \textbf{3E-205} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.04235 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.58395 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 6E-202 & 0.00E+00 & 2.82723 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.36289 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 6E-202 & 0.00E+00 & 2.47349 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.38523 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 6E-202 & 0.00E+00 & 2.56677 \\
    \midrule
    F5    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F6} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    SMA   & 3.78238 & 9.31239 & 2.3269 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 0.00103 & 0.00038 & 2.36232 \\
    CSMA1 & 1.10356 & 4.75533 & 2.81095 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA1}} & \textbf{0.00055} & \textbf{0.00026} & 2.62407 \\
    CSMA2 & 1.15974 & 4.84343 & 3.10878 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 0.00081 & 0.00024 & 2.51916 \\
    CSMA3 & 1.11759 & 4.78346 & 3.22669 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 0.00067 & 0.00029 & 2.55591 \\
    CSMA4 & 1.10857 & 4.83054 & 3.17664 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 0.00082 & 0.00029 & 2.53657 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{1.09376} & \textbf{4.80081} & 3.15938 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 0.00078 & 0.00028 & 2.48142 \\
    CSMA6 & 1.12998 & 4.75059 & 3.16403 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 0.00083 & 0.00032 & 2.6552 \\
    CSMA7 & 1.12702 & 4.79718 & 3.01073 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 0.00079 & 0.00027 & 2.45828 \\
    CSMA8 & 1.14092 & 4.85195 & 3.28944 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 0.00079 & 0.00035 & 2.75007 \\
    CSMA9 & 1.22858 & 5.14218 & 2.62418 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 0.00082 & 0.00033 & 2.48988 \\
    CSMA10 & 1.15403 & 4.86346 & 2.81456 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 0.00079 & 0.00029 & 2.49557 \\
    \midrule
    F7    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F8} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    SMA   & 8.2E-05 & 6.7E-05 & 2.29355 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & -12569.4 & 0.07418 & 2.35653 \\
    CSMA1 & 6.8E-05 & 5.9E-05 & 2.77366 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & -12569.4 & 0.06347 & 2.78339 \\
    CSMA2 & 6.3E-05 & 6.4E-05 & 2.64342 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & -12569.4 & 0.05164 & 2.6745 \\
    CSMA3 & 0.00011 & 0.00012 & 2.84265 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA3}} & \textbf{-12569.4} & \textbf{0.03755} & 3.68061 \\
    CSMA4 & 6E-05 & 7.9E-05 & 2.83622 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & -12569.4 & 0.06321 & 2.7465 \\
    CSMA5 & 5.2E-05 & 5E-05 & 2.71158 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & -12569.4 & 0.07631 & 2.60171 \\
    CSMA6 & 6.3E-05 & 6.4E-05 & 2.70197 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & -12569.4 & 0.04893 & 3.26204 \\
    CSMA7 & 6.7E-05 & 6.9E-05 & 2.65524 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & -12569.4 & 0.07372 & 3.12687 \\
    CSMA8 & 4.6E-05 & 4.4E-05 & 3.03288 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & -12569.4 & 0.07703 & 3.2881 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{4.3E-05} & \textbf{4.5E-05} & 2.74464 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & -12569.4 & 0.10229 & 3.0485 \\
    CSMA10 & 5.5E-05 & 6.3E-05 & 2.67424 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & -12569.4 & 0.07828 & 3.0532 \\
    \midrule
    F9    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F10} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.31204 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.42516 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.15072 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.93631 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.17613 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.98501 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.91965 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.01397 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.48282 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.88544 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.33479 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.76122 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.74962 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.23304 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.93211 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.21613 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.23546 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.44166 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.83562 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.11673 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.88957 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.24786 \\
    \midrule
    F11   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F12} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.31942 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 0.00089 & 0.00099 & 3.22927 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 4.14879 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 2.7E-05 & 1.4E-05 & 3.23443 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.13982 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 3.8E-05 & 2.3E-05 & 3.30638 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.08916 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA3}} & \textbf{2.3E-05} & \textbf{1.3E-05} & 3.14271 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.00935 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 4E-05 & 2.2E-05 & 3.08232 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.74957 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 4.7E-05 & 2.9E-05 & 3.68418 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.03787 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 4E-05 & 2.3E-05 & 3.54825 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.68593 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 4.1E-05 & 2.6E-05 & 3.46039 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.06393 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 4.9E-05 & 3E-05 & 3.51427 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.75799 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 4E-05 & 2.6E-05 & 3.00717 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.77517 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 4.1E-05 & 2.6E-05 & 2.92818 \\
    \midrule
    F13   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-4}    SMA   & 0.00149 & 0.0029 & 2.80562 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA1 & 0.00111 & 0.00278 & 3.41564 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA2 & 0.00095 & 0.00215 & 3.50876 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA3 & 0.00066 & 0.00199 & 3.72998 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA4 & 0.00089 & 0.00202 & 3.54897 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA5 & 0.00094 & 0.00098 & 3.42233 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA6 & 0.00087 & 0.002 & 3.64068 &       &       &       &  \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00053} & \textbf{0.0003} & 3.07592 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA8 & 0.00101 & 0.0021 & 3.68232 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA9 & 0.00056 & 0.00028 & 2.97613 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA10 & 0.00131 & 0.00283 & 3.01959 &       &       &       &  \\
    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Please show how you tried to use longtable or xltabular.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For a table that breaks across pages, you *have* to use `longtable` or `xltabular` (which brings the  functionalities of longtable to tabularx).

Comment: Please keep in mind that using `resizebox` on a table will result in inconsistent font sizes and line widths throughout the document. For better alternatives, you may want to take a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144). Also, horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package were designed to be used without vertical lines, hence the small gaps yround the intersections.

Comment: Why do you need `midrule` when you can use `hline` instead? Not explicitly mentioning `booktabs` package makes it uncompilable. And using `resizebox` with ampersands seem to be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I've gone through your suggestions and found my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table doesn't seem too wide and hence, fortunately, you can use the `longtable` option. The link provided by @leandriis has useful details on how to format your table on various situations. But to save you from all the details there for now, I gave this answer. You should use caption at the top of the longtable body followed by the label logically and then separate them using `\\` from the long table content, this is in contrast to the usual tables where you usually give at the bottom. Then to allow horizontal rules to appear at the start and end of table at each page breaks you need to use the combination of `endhead` and `endfoot` with rules in between.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{4.215em}rrr|rrrr}
  \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
  \endfirsthead\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    \midrule
    F1    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F2} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.4736 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 2E-189 & 0.00E+00 & 2.84143 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.17197 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 2E-184 & 0.00E+00 & 2.93863 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.84918 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.54477 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.78398 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 1E-197 & 0.00E+00 & 2.80703 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.18185 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.57635 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.03508 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA5}} & \textbf{5E-201} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.00535 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.33305 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.84252 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.05392 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 5E-197 & 0.00E+00 & 3.04812 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.03381 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 2E-196 & 0.00E+00 & 3.17601 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.00061 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 3.01033 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.07614 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 2E-200 & 0.00E+00 & 2.4786 \\
    \midrule
    F3    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F4} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.09959 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 7E-182 & 0.00E+00 & 2.37899 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.55129 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 4E-183 & 0.00E+00 & 3.05523 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.33676 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 1E-198 & 0.00E+00 & 2.65456 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.2895 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 2E-195 & 0.00E+00 & 2.95612 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.29967 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 2E-195 & 0.00E+00 & 2.65462 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.39968 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 1E-195 & 0.00E+00 & 2.90607 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.461 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 4E-205 & 0.00E+00 & 3.27635 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.35422 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA7}} & \textbf{3E-205} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.04235 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.58395 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 6E-202 & 0.00E+00 & 2.82723 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.36289 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 6E-202 & 0.00E+00 & 2.47349 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.38523 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 6E-202 & 0.00E+00 & 2.56677 \\
    \midrule
    F5    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F6} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    SMA   & 3.78238 & 9.31239 & 2.3269 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 0.00103 & 0.00038 & 2.36232 \\
    CSMA1 & 1.10356 & 4.75533 & 2.81095 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA1}} & \textbf{0.00055} & \textbf{0.00026} & 2.62407 \\
    CSMA2 & 1.15974 & 4.84343 & 3.10878 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 0.00081 & 0.00024 & 2.51916 \\
    CSMA3 & 1.11759 & 4.78346 & 3.22669 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 0.00067 & 0.00029 & 2.55591 \\
    CSMA4 & 1.10857 & 4.83054 & 3.17664 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 0.00082 & 0.00029 & 2.53657 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{1.09376} & \textbf{4.80081} & 3.15938 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 0.00078 & 0.00028 & 2.48142 \\
    CSMA6 & 1.12998 & 4.75059 & 3.16403 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 0.00083 & 0.00032 & 2.6552 \\
    CSMA7 & 1.12702 & 4.79718 & 3.01073 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 0.00079 & 0.00027 & 2.45828 \\
    CSMA8 & 1.14092 & 4.85195 & 3.28944 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 0.00079 & 0.00035 & 2.75007 \\
    CSMA9 & 1.22858 & 5.14218 & 2.62418 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 0.00082 & 0.00033 & 2.48988 \\
    CSMA10 & 1.15403 & 4.86346 & 2.81456 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 0.00079 & 0.00029 & 2.49557 \\
    \midrule
    F7    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F8} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    SMA   & 8.2E-05 & 6.7E-05 & 2.29355 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & -12569.4 & 0.07418 & 2.35653 \\
    CSMA1 & 6.8E-05 & 5.9E-05 & 2.77366 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & -12569.4 & 0.06347 & 2.78339 \\
    CSMA2 & 6.3E-05 & 6.4E-05 & 2.64342 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & -12569.4 & 0.05164 & 2.6745 \\
    CSMA3 & 0.00011 & 0.00012 & 2.84265 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA3}} & \textbf{-12569.4} & \textbf{0.03755} & 3.68061 \\
    CSMA4 & 6E-05 & 7.9E-05 & 2.83622 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & -12569.4 & 0.06321 & 2.7465 \\
    CSMA5 & 5.2E-05 & 5E-05 & 2.71158 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & -12569.4 & 0.07631 & 2.60171 \\
    CSMA6 & 6.3E-05 & 6.4E-05 & 2.70197 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & -12569.4 & 0.04893 & 3.26204 \\
    CSMA7 & 6.7E-05 & 6.9E-05 & 2.65524 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & -12569.4 & 0.07372 & 3.12687 \\
    CSMA8 & 4.6E-05 & 4.4E-05 & 3.03288 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & -12569.4 & 0.07703 & 3.2881 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{4.3E-05} & \textbf{4.5E-05} & 2.74464 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & -12569.4 & 0.10229 & 3.0485 \\
    CSMA10 & 5.5E-05 & 6.3E-05 & 2.67424 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & -12569.4 & 0.07828 & 3.0532 \\
    \midrule
    F9    & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F10} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.31204 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.42516 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.15072 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.93631 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.17613 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.98501 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.91965 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA3} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.01397 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.48282 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.88544 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.33479 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 2.76122 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.74962 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.23304 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.93211 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.21613 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.23546 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.44166 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.83562 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.11673 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.88957 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 8.9E-16 & 0.00E+00 & 3.24786 \\
    \midrule
    F11   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{F12} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Time} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{SMA} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.31942 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{SMA} & 0.00089 & 0.00099 & 3.22927 \\
    \textbf{CSMA1} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 4.14879 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA1} & 2.7E-05 & 1.4E-05 & 3.23443 \\
    \textbf{CSMA2} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.13982 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA2} & 3.8E-05 & 2.3E-05 & 3.30638 \\
    \textbf{CSMA3} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.08916 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{CSMA3}} & \textbf{2.3E-05} & \textbf{1.3E-05} & 3.14271 \\
    \textbf{CSMA4} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.00935 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA4} & 4E-05 & 2.2E-05 & 3.08232 \\
    \textbf{CSMA5} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.74957 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA5} & 4.7E-05 & 2.9E-05 & 3.68418 \\
    \textbf{CSMA6} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.03787 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA6} & 4E-05 & 2.3E-05 & 3.54825 \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.68593 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA7} & 4.1E-05 & 2.6E-05 & 3.46039 \\
    \textbf{CSMA8} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 3.06393 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA8} & 4.9E-05 & 3E-05 & 3.51427 \\
    \textbf{CSMA9} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.75799 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA9} & 4E-05 & 2.6E-05 & 3.00717 \\
    \textbf{CSMA10} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & \textbf{0.00E+00} & 2.77517 & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{CSMA10} & 4.1E-05 & 2.6E-05 & 2.92818 \\
    \midrule
    F13   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{Time} &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-4}    SMA   & 0.00149 & 0.0029 & 2.80562 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA1 & 0.00111 & 0.00278 & 3.41564 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA2 & 0.00095 & 0.00215 & 3.50876 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA3 & 0.00066 & 0.00199 & 3.72998 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA4 & 0.00089 & 0.00202 & 3.54897 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA5 & 0.00094 & 0.00098 & 3.42233 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA6 & 0.00087 & 0.002 & 3.64068 &       &       &       &  \\
    \textbf{CSMA7} & \textbf{0.00053} & \textbf{0.0003} & 3.07592 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA8 & 0.00101 & 0.0021 & 3.68232 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA9 & 0.00056 & 0.00028 & 2.97613 &       &       &       &  \\
    CSMA10 & 0.00131 & 0.00283 & 3.01959 &       &       &       &  \\
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I have worked around this and found my solution I was looking for.